# E-mail background image works as URL but not as directory

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, email-attachments

I'm trying to make my email background working.
When I'm using:

```
style="background: #3b72bb url('https://s1.postimg.org/sample/image.jpg') no-repeat; background-size: cover;"
```

it works fine.

But as I'm using:

```
style="background: #3b72bb url('img/image.jpg') no-repeat; background-size: cover;
```

I can no longer see my background image.

Folder Structure is:

```
index.html
img/
    image.jpg
```

I'm using platform that sends images alongside with `index.html`.
Images as:

```
<img src="img/leftphoto.jpg" alt="" width="274" height="550" border="0" style="color: #1f1f1f; border: none; display: block; font-size: 12px; line-height: 34px; text-align: left;">
```

Are working perfectly.
I had tried various options as:

```
style="background: #3b72bb url('/img/image.jpg') no-repeat; background-size: cover;
style="background: #3b72bb url('../img/image.jpg') no-repeat; background-size: cover;
```

And one at the begining. None of them are working.
It needs to be send as an image, not as URL.

Comment: You'll need to stick to absolute file paths, the email client has to download images from the server remotely so it needs to know where to look.

Comment: Can you write sample path?

Comment: http://yourserver.whatever/images/yourimage.jpg. local paths work for YOU because you have the image on your computer. Get that?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to upload the content, the images in this case to a remote server which can be accessed with an **absolute** url. [It's not possible](https://kb.mailchimp.com/templates/code/common-html-mistakes) to use local image files, as @UncaughtTypeError noted.

The cheapest and fastest solution would be to upload your content to an image hosting service such as [imgur](https://imgur.com/). Best would be to host your own server and have the content uploaded there, this way you can assure the files from being accessible in the future.

Comment: ALWAYS use absolute URLs in html emails :D This answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Background images do not work across all email clients. They do not work in some instances of Gmail, Outlook, Windows Mail and a few others. In Outlook and Windows, they work if you use vml.

- https://backgrounds.cm

More information on what works with background images.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/background-image/

In addition, as mentioned, you need to have an absolute path for the image that can be accessible to any email client.

This works:

```
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" alt="Mountain">
```

This does not:

```
<img src="/images/picture.jpg" alt="Mountain">
```

Comment: @MarcinMaicki You're right, it's just Google Android IMAP. -
 https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/background-image/